# Find directories that have .csv files

Tags: bash, find

Here is a `find` command that I have:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d -exec find {} -type f -name "*.csv" \;
```

In fact, it is a `find` command within a `find` command. For every directory in my current directory, it checks to see if a file ends with `.csv`.

What I want, is for this command to print out the name of the directory that does contain a file that ends with `.csv`. Is this possible using the command above, or should I try a different solution?